# How to render ng-template from host element?

Tags: angular

How to render only `pending`?

I build a layout component and I wrap each section with `ng-template` because I don't want to render the content immediately.

How to only render `ng-template#pending`?

```
<search [results]="searchResults$ | async" [pending]="pending$ | async">
  <form filter ...>...</form>
  <ng-template #empty>empty!</ng-template>
  <ng-template #pending>please wait..</ng-template>
  <ng-template let-context>
    <card *ngFor="let result of context.results">...</card>
  </ng-template>
</search>
```

I use this component like that:

```
 <ng-content select="[filter]"></ng-content>
 ??? <--- here, what I write here in order to render ng-template of #pending?
```

Comment: I don't understand. Why not using some `*ngIf` if you don't want to render the content immediately ? Something like `<div *ngIf="status==='PENDING'">[...]</div>`

Comment: what about `empty`? lets say I solve with status like you said. but my issue is about render ng-template from the host inside the component. only from the selector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to use ContentChild decorator to get projected ng-template reference  in the search component and then pass template reference variables to it.

**search.component.ts**

```
  @ContentChild('pending') pendingTemplateRef:TemplateRef<any>;
```

Then in html you have to use NgTemplateOutlet directive to render it

**search.component.html**

```
<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="pendingTemplateRef">
</ng-container>
```

**[Working Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ykth9k?file=src/app/search/search.component.html)**